# Pythonic pattern for building up parallel lists

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I am new-ish to Python and I am finding that I am writing the same pattern of code over and over again:

```
def foo(list):
    results = []
    for n in list:
        #do some or a lot of processing on N and possibly other variables
        nprime = operation(n)
        results.append(nprime)
    return results
```

I am thinking in particular about the creation of the empty list followed by the `append` call.  Is there a more Pythonic way to express this pattern?  `append` might not have the best performance characteristics, but I am not sure how else I would approach it in Python.

I often know exactly the length of my output, so calling `append` each time seems like it might be causing memory fragmentation, or performance problems, but I am also wondering if that is just my old `C` ways tripping me up.  I am writing a lot of text parsing code that isn't super performance sensitive on any particular loop or piece because all of the performance is really contained in `gensim` or `NLTK` code and is in much more capable hands than mine.

Is there a better/more pythonic pattern for doing this type of operation?

Comment: Repeated appending is fine. Trying to preallocate your list, while possible, isn't likely to provide a substantial performance improvement, and might easily slow things down.

Comment: Do you mean the extra processing precludes using a list comprehension `return [operation(n) for n in list]`?

Comment: Depending on the amount of `some or a lot of processing`, [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) or their cousins generator expressions can give a speed or memory benefit over the simple for loop. If `some or a lot of processing` is more than a line or two of code, however, the for loop definitely wins out on readability and maintainability.

Comment: If the processing doesn't fit neatly into a list comprehension as @chepner suggests, your for loop method is the next best choice.

Comment: The processing definitely doesn't fit into loop comprehension.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, a list comprehension may be all you need (if all the processing mentioned in your comment occurs in `operation`.

```
def foo(list):
    return [operation(n) for n in list]
```

---

If a list comprehension will not work in your situation, consider whether `foo` really needs to build the list and could be a generator instead.

```
def foo(list):
    for n in list:
        # Processing...
        yield operation(n)
```

In this case, you can iterate over the sequence, and each value is calculated on demand:

```
for x in foo(myList):
   ...
```

or you can let the caller decide if a full list is needed:

```
results = list(foo())
```

---

If neither of the above is suitable, then building up the return list in the body of the loop as you are now is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: I think there is definitely room in my code for more generators.  There are probably a number of places that would make my code read a little better and be better composed.  Thanks!  (I'll see what else comes in, but I think adding generators when appropriate is the answer I am looking for and will mark it as such)

Answer (score 4):

> [..] so calling `append` each time seems like it might be causing memory fragmentation, or performance problems, but I am also wondering if that is just my old C ways tripping me up.

If you are worried about this, don't. Python over-allocates when a new resizing of the list is required (lists are dynamically resized based on their size) in order to perform `O(1)` appends. Either you manually call `list.append` or build it with a list comprehension (which internally *also* uses `.append`) the effect, memory wise, is similar.

The list-comprehension just performs (speed wise) a bit better; it is optimized for creating lists with specialized byte-code instructions that aid it (`LIST_APPEND` mainly that *directly* calls lists append in `C`).

Of course, if memory usage is of concern, you could always opt for the generator approach as highlighted in chepners answer to lazily produce your results.

---

In the end, `for` loops are still great. They might seem clunky in comparison to comprehensions and `map`s but they still offer a recognizable and readable way to achieve a goal. `for` loops deserve our love too.

Comment: Not to mention that list comprehension requires the usage of a `for` :)